# Where are Caillou's items?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

Caillou is looking for Charred Lizard, Bat Wings, and Slime Liver. I've never seen any of these items for sale or dropped by monsters. Where do I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can all be found in the Green Way.

Kobolds (the furry brown things who throw nuts at you) and Reginald Drisby (Rat Boss) drop the Charred Lizard, The Crowned Slime drops the Slime Liver, and the Bat Wings are from the floating eye things (Eyebats).

Comment: I've never seen normal slimes of any color drop Slime Livers. You sure about that one? Caillou even notes in an event (should you be late to deliver) that it's only the big ones that will produce Slime Livers.

Comment: @Grace - completely possible. I may be thinking of Slime Stones, another, visually identical Slime drop.

Comment: Aye, Slime Stones can be dropped (very rarely) by the more powerful Slimes, as well as the Crowned Slimes. Which reminds me, I need a couple more of those. Accursed not-dropping-items...